# compare the month part with linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I want to compare the month part of two values in linq but im getting an error

> property or indexer DateTime.Month cannot be assigned to

Here's the code

```
var item = model.Where(d => d.DATE2.Date.Month = dto.StartDate.Month).FirstOrDefault();
```

`model` is a list of objects with datetime properties and the dto.Startdate is also a datetime

Comment: use == to compare

Comment: You should really look at some c# beginner tutorials before trying to use LinQ

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Why? Because thats going to tell you you made a simple typo on equality comparison?

Comment: @Jamiec because it will explain simple operators, common errors and what they mean

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto but literally every question here could be answered with "google it" or "go read a book". It's considered a bit of a rude comment.

Comment: @Jamiec not really every question, no, I don't believe that. And that's why the downvote button clearly says "lack of research"

Answer (score 8):

You may not come up with this question if you read the error message carefully, since its clear enough. Anyway, you have to use `==` here for comparing two values, `=` is for assignment purpose(basic knowledge). After making this small change your query will look like the following:

```
var item = model.Where(d => d.DATE2.Date.Month == dto.StartDate.Month).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can make them even simple by using `FirstOrDefault` instead for `Where` as like this:

```
 var item = model.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DATE2.Date.Month == dto.StartDate.Month);
```

Comment: yeah I figured that out myself, my bad :-)

Comment: its a case of "i needed to take a break"

Comment: and yeah, his comment was rude